Eggplant Functional - writing to json file
I'm creating a new patient in my test system. I have extracted the text using search rectangles to read the text and log the output. Since I'm putting a random number generator at the end of the patients name, I'm needing to dynamically read the patient name (+the random characters) and then write that to a json file.
I have the patient name nested under Patient Info. I can read from here but I'm trying to write the newly captured patient name. Also, would be beneficial if we could remove the existing or create a copy of the json file and replace the existing with the new info. I think that's how we would have to go about this. Any insights on the syntax in how to write to a json file would be appreciated.
Here's what I tried after extracting the patient name and putting it into  variable but neither write/nor put worked for me. Thanks.
Set DataFile To JSONValue(File ResourcePath("PatientCreate.json"))
Write Patient To JSONFormat(DataFile.PatientCreate.PatientInfo.Name)
Put JSONFormat(Patient) Into (DataFile.PatientCreate.PatientInfo.Name)

I think I understand what you are trying to do, but correct me if I'm wrong.
The below example is taking some data, making it into a string, then outputting that string as nicely formatted JSON into a file:
// in your example, this would be the name captured from the screen
put "Jane Doe" into capturedPatientName

// Here is where we join the captured name with other information 
// (perhaps read in from another json file
// to create a JSON-like string 
put {patientName: capturedPatientName, patientNumber: 1234} into userInfo

// Put the string into well formatted JSON and 
// write out to a file of your choosing
put userInfo's JSONFormat into file "C:\temp\output.json"

Please let me know if that makes sense or if I can be of more help!
